# Tracking units over time if one value is smaller than another value

Tags: loops, stata

I want to track the same group over time. Consider the data example below. Group = 4933 first appears in 2008 and `treated = 1 if previous < sale & enter == year`. I want to spread this 1 to all other group = 4933 but not when year is 2010, for example, because in 2010 there is a new entry of director ID and his group after 2010 should be spread. Thus, I need treated = 1 for group = 709 in 2011 as well.
Treatment is the entering of a director whose previous value is smaller than sale of a firm. And treatment should be 1 for this director up until he leaves the company.

```
    clear

input treated   previous    enter   group   dirid   fid year    sale    exit
0   .   2006    2073    41610   11  2008    5.124932    2011
0   .   2007    1139    17558   11  2008    5.124932    2011
1   2.796215    2008    4933    238853  11  2008    5.124932    2011
0   .   2006    2070    41584   11  2008    5.124932    2011
0   .   2006    2075    41649   11  2008    5.124932    2011
0   2.796215    2008    4933    238853  11  2009    5.623706    2011
0   .   2007    1139    17558   11  2009    5.623706    2011
0   .   2006    2073    41610   11  2009    5.623706    2011
0   .   2006    2070    41584   11  2009    5.623706    2011
0   .   2006    2075    41649   11  2009    5.623706    2011
0   .   2009    2078    41712   11  2009    5.623706    2011
0   .   2006    2075    41649   11  2010    5.659729    2011
0   .   2006    2070    41584   11  2010    5.659729    2011
0   .   2007    1139    17558   11  2010    5.659729    2011
0   2.796215    2008    4933    238853  11  2010    5.659729    2011
1   5.123736    2010    709 9587    11  2010    5.659729    2011
0   .   2009    2078    41712   11  2010    5.659729    2011
0   .   2006    2073    41610   11  2010    5.659729    2011
0   .   2007    1139    17558   11  2011    5.513114    2011
0   .   2006    2073    41610   11  2011    5.513114    2011
0   .   2009    2078    41712   11  2011    5.513114    2011
0   2.796215    2008    4933    238853  11  2011    5.513114    2011
0   .   2006    2070    41584   11  2011    5.513114    2011
0   5.123736    2010    709 9587    11  2011    5.513114    2011
0   .   2006    2075    41649   11  2011    5.513114    2011
end
```

I tried this code:

```
sum dirid
forval i=9587 /238853{
    qui replace treated0 =1 if dirid == `i' & enter <year & !missing(previous) 
}
```

but it replaces also group=4933 in 2010. I don't need this, it should only be one for group = 709.

Comment: Your data example shows 8 values in some observations and 9 in the others.

Comment: Sorry, missing values disappeared. Now I corrected it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I can't follow this. Note your loop is not really a loop and could be a single statement `replace treated0 =1 if inrange(dirid, 9587, 238853) & enter <year & !missing(previous)`.